# Booting users from SQL Server

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2, offline

I'm not sure how to even ask this question. We are running SQL Server 2008 R2. I'm not the admin, but a programmer. I need to write an application that updates some database stuff at night. I'm going to set a flag to disable logins to the database, but I want to make a particular database unavailable to anyone except me, even if someone is already logged in to the database. My program will run nightly, as a batch file, presumably with admin privileges.

I'm expecting to produce something like a script of SQL commands. I could take the database offline, except I need to make modifications to it myself. Not sure the best way to handle this.

Comment: Tell us a little bit more about why the database has to be unaccessible during your updates. If you are worried about concurrency, why not wrap your updates in explicit transactions? Also, is the "database stuff" purely DML or with some DDL mixed in (index rebuild, etc)?

Comment: The way I have to do this is I completely reload new data from an external source every night (and then update any stuff that was updated from the old data, then erase the old data).  This is the way the problem was defined to me - I cannot change it.  I'll search on ldap.

Comment: DML.  I may need to add indices later, but not for now.

Comment: i misunderstood ... you just need to do daily backup of the database?

Comment: A little more than backup, although I am going to use the backup function to get around database copying.  I'm going to swap databases between the new and 'old', zero out the new, upload entirely new information into the new, and then update the new from the old, but only new records that have been added.  (note that old is the previous day's new).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can basically just set the database to "single-user" mode and use it exclusively - this T-SQL will do this:

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
```

(of course - replace `AdventureWorks2012` with your own database name!)

This will make the database "single-user", e.g. only you have access to it, and it will boot off any users that's currently online, and will rollback all open transactions.

[Read more about single user mode on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598.aspx)!

> This example sets the database to SINGLE_USER mode to obtain exclusive access. The termination option `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` is specified in the first `ALTER DATABASE` statement. This will cause all incomplete transactions to be rolled back and **any other connections to the AdventureWorks2012 database to be immediately disconnected.**

Comment: Will that boot people who are already logged in?  I thought it might give me an error.  I'll experiment with this one too when I get the access I need.

Comment: @elbillaf: **read the docs!** on MSDN - yes, this will boot out current connections...

Comment: I was reading the docs just now...yes...I see...thanks. That's perfect.

Comment: A cleaner solution yet so simple I don't even know why I didn't think of it when I needed it.

Comment: Ah, I wish you left the other one up, too. More stuff to google.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using an administrative account to perform the updates, I'll assume the account is in one of these roles: `db_owner`, `dbcreator`, `sysadmin`. Use the [`ALTER DATABASE SET ...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) syntax to control database access during the DML operations.

**The assumption is that database users you want to lock out aren't in the above mentioned roles.**

```
USE master;

-- only allow members of db_owner, dbcreator, or sysadmin roles to access
-- database, allowing current transactions time to complete. if you want to
-- drop access immediately, add WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
ALTER DATABASE SET RESTRICTED_USER;

-- data load

-- return database to normal operating state
ALTER DATABASE SET MULTI_USER;
```

Comment: That's not true at this moment, but it will be true. I'll try that one.